# Slideshow Pro - Flash loads but images do not. Why?

Tags: flash, slideshow, swfobject

I installed Slideshow pro, with swfobject here: http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/whos-involved/alumni

The flash loads but the images do not. I have double checked the image paths to death and they appear to be correct.

Here is the html:

```
<object id="alumni" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="520" height="270">
<param name="movie" value="http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/alumni-slideshow.swf" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/alumni-slideshow.swf" width="520" height="270">

<!--<![endif]-->
<div>
    <h1>Alternative content</h1>
    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/photos/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
</div>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->

</object>
```

Here is the swfobject code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.registerObject("slideshow", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
    swfobject.registerObject("alumni", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
</script>
```

The images.xml file and the gallery are both in the root directory and the xml file code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <gallery>
   <album title="Alumni" description="Duke Global Health Institute Alumni" lgPath="gallery/album1/lg/">
  <img src="kohler.jpg" />
  <img src="zimmerman.jpg" />
  <img src="griffin.jpg" />
   </album>
</gallery>
```

I would appreciate some help in resolving this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the folks over at Slideshow Pro I finally figured out the solution:

1. Put the full url to the images.xml in the ssp preferences in Flash: http://www.myurl.com/images.xml
2. Put the full path to the gallery images folder in the xml file: http://www.myurl.com/gallery/lg/
3. Only put the name of the image in the img src link: img src="photo1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

okay, are you ready, you putted all of them into root, and access now this url
http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/alumni-slideshow.swf

end embed it where you want.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I tried that path and get the same results. The xml file and the gallery are in the same directory. This looks like it should make sense but shouldn't the ../../ be between the page and the .xml file? However, the connection is being made with the swf file. Any other thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I left that path intact so you can give it a try.

Comment: no it is not, http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/whos-involved/alumni/image.xml returns 404

Comment: actually the xml path is: http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/images.xml and the path to the photos is: http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/gallery/album1/lg/

Comment: man, put your application into the root too, not two subfolders else, just root!

Comment: I like your style. All three are in the root folder. The images.xml, gallery and alumni-slideshow.swf. Is there anything else?

Comment: if its running enough well for you and you are like - then its all, if you need anything else - let me know. and don't forget to accept answer and rate the comments.

Comment: Eugene. Sorry I missed your comment there. The problem is that it is not working. The pictures still do not load.

Comment: stop, i saw your link with root swf file, where is it? I checked it and it works, what did you change? can you again past all data into the one folder?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue with crossdomain.xml and my Apache mod_rewrite rule which was directing all **domain.com** requests to **www.domain.com**.

I added this to my .htaccess file and it started working again:

```
RewriteRule ^/crossdomain\.xml$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [redirect=permanent]
```